# How do I initialize a class over the course of several view controllers

Tags: swift, xcode, class, option-type

I have an `Event` class that has variables such as `Date`, `Time`, `Activity`, etc. The user can create an `Event` with a series of view controllers that let the user construct it one variable at a time, sort of like a walkthrough. My issue is in order to initialize the `Event` on the first screen I use an empty initializer, and all of the instance variables are optional by default. As the user walks through the screens, they are set accordingly. How would I properly initialize this class over time? Using optionals for all variables seems improper.

Id like to initialize the `Event` on the first screen like this:

```
var event = Event()
```

And set it's instance variables one by one without them all being optional.

Comment: "Id like to initialize..." Nope. You can't initialize a class over time. You can set an instance's properties over time. That being the case, what you're doing seems fine. Don't worry be happy.

Comment: However, alternatively you could keep calling into a Builder that creates the Event fully formed only when all the needed info has been provided.

Comment: @matt how would a builder function like that work? How would it add onto the same event on every call? Or would the variables still have to be optional?

Comment: It wouldn't matter what the variable of the Builder are, because they will be private. It's just functions: input functions so that clients can supply info, and an output function so that the Builder can supply the fully formed Event. The point is that, on this model, the Event doesn't need any Optional properties, because the Builder doesn't instantiate it until it has all the info.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't initialize a class over time. You can set an instance's properties over time. That being the case, what you're doing seems fine.
However, alternatively you could keep calling into a builder that creates the Event fully formed only when all the needed info has been provided. Imagine an architecture like this (try it out in your playground):

```
class Event : CustomStringConvertible {
    let fee : String
    let fi : String
    let fo : String
    let fum : String
    init(fee:String, fi:String, fo:String, fum:String) {
        self.fee = fee; self.fi = fi; self.fo = fo; self.fum = fum
    }
    var description : String {
        "Event: \(fee) \(fi) \(fo) \(fum)"
    }
}

class EventBuilder {
    private var fee : String?
    private var fi : String?
    private var fo : String?
    private var fum : String?
    private var event : Event?
    private func makeEventIfPossible() {
        guard event == nil else {return}
        if let fee = fee,
           let fi = fi,
           let fo = fo,
           let fum = fum {
            print("making event")
            self.event = Event(fee: fee, fi: fi, fo: fo, fum: fum)
        }
    }
    func takeFee(_ fee:String) {
        self.fee = fee
        makeEventIfPossible()
    }
    func takeFi(_ fi:String) {
        self.fi = fi
        makeEventIfPossible()
    }
    func takeFo(_ fo:String) {
        self.fo = fo
        makeEventIfPossible()
    }
    func takeFum(_ fum:String) {
        self.fum = fum
        makeEventIfPossible()
    }
    func giveEvent() -> Event? {
        self.event
    }
}

let b = EventBuilder()
b.takeFee("Fee")
b.takeFi("Fi")
b.takeFo("Fo")
b.takeFum("Fum")
if let event = b.giveEvent() {
    print(event) // and away we go
}
```

You can pass the EventBuilder around, different objects can call different `take` methods, and no one can get the Event with `giveEvent` until all the info has been supplied and the Event has been created. As you can see, the Event is created just once, and none of its properties are Optional. The builder hides the whole creation process behind a functional representation (hence the name).

I can imagine further refinements, like you could make the `take` methods `throws` methods where they would refuse to accept a value if that value had already been set, and so on. Also I think you might use keypaths somehow to make the code neater/smaller.